# How this code is generated?

Tags: android, algorithm, encryption, whatsapp

I got this code from github and if i'm not wrong, this is used as WhatsApp signature during account registration process.

Here's the code

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

Can somebody explain to me how this code is generated? What should I do if I want to generate my own code like this? Asking this because want to know what's really behind this code..

Comment: It's Base64-encoded. We can't really know what all of the original data is, or how it's meant to be handled, but if you plug it into any online decoder, you'll see embedded, human-readable strings.

Comment: Thanks but can you please explain how they got it here? https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/blob/master/src/token.php

Comment: Oh, that's what you mean. Nope, not really. I don't do WhatsApp.

Comment: Ya Mike. And like you said, I tried to decode it with an online decoder and even though it's not fully human-readable, it's infact the signature details of the WhatsApp apk. But no idea how this code is generated.

Answer (score 1):

this is [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) code,used for security purposes, whatsapp created using some encryption algorithm(which is kept secret),but you can also generate similar one using [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) or [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shlok but my question is, how could somebody else get this code? see here https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/blob/master/src/token.php